# Convert Set to List

Tags: flutter, dart

Need help in Converting `Set<>` to `List<String>` in Flutter

```dart
Set<_Filter> _selectedFilters = Set<_Filter>();

final List<_Filter> _filters = [
  _Filter('Bee Cattle'),
  _Filter('Crops'),
  _Filter('Machinery'),
  _Filter('Fish'),
  _Filter('Sheep'),
  _Filter('Cattle Breeds'),
  _Filter('Wells'),
  _Filter('Farm'),
];
```

I need to convert this Set to `List<string>`.

Comment: There is a `toList` method on `Set`, just do `_selectedFilters.toList()`

Comment: It is not a Set of strings, so just using `toList` will create a `List_Filter>`. So *which* strings do you want to convert the set elements to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use the [`Iterable.toList` method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html), i.e. in your case `Set.toList`.

```dart
final Set<String> set = {'cake', 'cookie'};

final List<String> list = set.toList();
```